# Kotlin Only one class may appear in a supertype list

Tags: android, kotlin

I am running into trouble with having two superclasses. When I am adding the PreferenceFragment() I am recieving the error: **Only one class may appear in a supertype list**.

Any ideas on how I can work around this problem?

```
class MyAccountFragment @Inject constructor(): BaseFragment(), PreferenceFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun initView() {
    }

    override fun initEvent() {
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Base Fragment and Preference Fragment both extend from Fragment so MyFragment has to pick one to inherit from.

Comment: Post what your BaseFragment looks like and we can go from there

Comment: Using DaggerFragment in the Base for DI

Comment: Also I’m noticing that you have an @Inject annotation on MyFragment. Are you using the FragmentFactory api in your project?

Comment: Don’t use daggerfragment if you need other specialized fragments. Use the alternative HasAndroidInjector interface

Comment: More to the point, java doesn’t allow multiple class inheritance.

Comment: If you share your `BaseFragment`, we may be able to rewrite it without needing inheritance.

Comment: Thanks @flopshot used HasAndroidInjector

Comment: Kotlin and Java don't allow multiple class inheritance @LukePhillips